# Giving error when open child form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am going to make a desktop application with telerik desktop controls.
My main form code is :

```
 public partial class MainForm3 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
       {
        private string ISadmin = string.Empty;
        private string Customer_ID = string.Empty;
        private string sLanguage_Code = "en-US";
        private string Contact_ID = string.Empty;
        public MainForm3(string Contact_IDa, string Customer_IDa, string ISadmina)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Contact_ID = Contact_IDa;
            this.Customer_ID = Customer_IDa;
            this.ISadmin = ISadmina;  
        }
        private void MainForm3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
                    this.radDock1.AutoDetectMdiChildren = true;
                }
        private void radMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormThree formthree= new FormThree ();
            formthree.MdiParent = this;
            formthree.Show();
        }

    }
```

string Contact_IDa, string Customer_IDa, string ISadmina are from login page

login page code:

```
if(login success){

//setup necessary values 



 System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new  System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
 t.Start();
 this.Close();

}

public void ThreadProc()
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm3(Contact_ID, Customer_ID, IsAdmin));
        }
```

> and FormThree Codes are ;

```
public partial class FormThree : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
           {
        public FormThree ()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            splitPanel1.AllowDrop = true;
            splitPanel1.DragEnter += splitPanel1_DragEnter;
            splitPanel1.DragDrop += splitPanel1_DragDrop;
        }
        private void splitPanel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] filePaths = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));

                foreach (string fileLoc in filePaths)
                {
                    // Code to read the contents of the text file
                    if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
                    {
                        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
                        {
                            string Name = Path.GetFileName(fileLoc);
                            string extention = Path.GetExtension(fileLoc);
                            MessageBox.Show("Name:" + Name + " </br>Extention:" + extention);
                            //MessageBox.Show(tr.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void splitPanel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

        private void FormThree_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Now problem is 
when i click "radMenuItem1" for load my form FormThree it say 
"DragDrop registration did not succeed." why and how can i fix this problem.....

Comment: May I ask you why you are starting MainForm3 on a different thread? This could very difficult to handle in your application.

Comment: So what is the good solution?? I am beginner .

Comment: Just don't use a thread, there is no point.  Simply call the Show() method to display the MainForm3 instance.  Btw, this exception is raised because you forgot to call the thread's SetApartmentState() to make it an STA thread.  Required to support D+D.

Answer (score 0):

Start your application as every application starts.
In your Main method do:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm3());
```

No parameters here in the constructor, then in your MainForm3 constructor (before the InitializeComponent) do the login opening a dedicated modal form to get the login credentials needed to continue.

If the login fails, you could inform the user and close the application with Application.Exit().
If the login is successful read the values needed for you MainForm3. No need to start a different
thread